# When does do-support apply in wh-questions?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

For reference, I'm working off of Carnie's *Syntax* (2002). In the book's framework, T → C movement is triggered by a [+Q] feature in C. In the case we have an auxiliary verb, it can raise to T and then to C to make subject-aux inversion, like in *Can we eat?* In the case we don't have an auxiliary, but rather a null tense head (to mark present or past tense), we get *do*-support: Carnie says that when there is no other option for supporting inflectional affixes, we insert the dummy verb *do* into T. This would then move into the C head as in the picture below. However, I'm wondering about sentences such as *Who kissed Matt?* or *Who gave you that present?*—since these aren't necessarily echo questions and there are no auxiliaries, why don't we have *do*-support in these questions? There would be a null past tense head in T, but the way I understand *do*-support, we must add *do* to support tense inflection if we have T → C movement in a question; however, something like **Who did kiss Matt?* is ungrammatical to me. Could someone help illuminate what the tree and movement operations would be like under this framework?
[image: a wh-question with do-support]

Comment: I think your question may be the same in essence as this one: [Why is there no Subject-Auxilliary inversion in Subject questions?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26586/why-is-there-no-subject-auxilliary-inversion-in-subject-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is addressed in challenge problem set 1 with the example *Who ate the pizza?*, so you're right in noticing that this is a problem! I am no expert, but I see two options:

The first is to not set [+Q] on the complementizer, so that it does not need a phonological realization. This seems unlikely semantically.

The second would be to say that T-to-C movement of non-auxiliaries is available in English **when Spec,TP is empty**. Then you are allowed to move the verb from V to T to C, checking [+Q]. In object Wh-questions, Spec,TP is filled with the subject; the movement would be blocked and do-support is required. Recall from the section on do-support that it is always a last resort: it is not used unless absolutely necessary; hence *Who did kiss Matt* is ungrammatical because you can use *kiss* to fill the C head and do not need *did* to do so.

Again, I'm no expert, so there may be problems with this analysis or there may be other solutions still.